# resources not shown in intellisense wpf

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, intellisense

intellisense not showing any resources in my other loaded projects
he shows my the resources in current projects but showing the other resources in other attached project

```
    <UserControl x:Class="SelectionPlus.UI.Data.SelectableListControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SelectionPlus.UI.Data"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 x:Name="SelectableListUserControl"
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged">
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;Component/Resources/Colors.xaml"/>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;Component/Resources/Fonts.xaml"/>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;Component/Resources/Text.xaml"/>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;Component/Resources/ToolBar.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <Style x:Key="MainUserControl" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 3 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource control.Border.Thickness}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Normal.BR.Color}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
...............
</Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Name="contentControl" Style="{StaticResource MainUserControl}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I type StaticResource its showsmy only ResourceKey property and nothing of my resource in resource project but when i copy paste the resource key , it show in run time or resolved
how to back them back to my intellisense again
many thanks in advance

Comment: I found the problem & solution
its because of target frame work in both project are different
in resource 4.5.2 and in my project is 4.7.2
when i make both 4.5.2 or 4.7.2 its working fine and resource can be shown in intellisense fine
thanks

Comment: unfortunately, i'm prevented from adding solutions :(

Comment: You can check this: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: many thanks for you, this sound very good, but i must have min of 15 reputation to do that, which i don't know how to earn them , any way many thanks for your concern and i will do when i get the credit

Comment: many thanks for your help, support and valued reputation points
i could did it now and i add the answer

Comment: ok, i did , many  thanks for usual support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem & solution its because of target frame work in both project are different, 
in resource dll file, target .net is 4.5.2 and in my project is 4.7.2 
when i make both 4.5.2 or 4.7.2 its working fine and resource can be shown in intellisense fine
thanks